# How to link external DLLs properly in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, dll, qt5, qmake

Am trying to build the project found @ [uconfig](https://github.com/Robotips/uConfig)
, the project requires poppler and the author provided pre-built links 
[headers](http://robotips.fr/data/bin-poppler-win32.tar.gz) and [DLLS](http://robotips.fr/data/include-poppler.tar.gz)

I have downloaded them and this is structure of the project

[image]

**dll** folder contains all the DLLS and **poppler** contains header files,
the **pdf_extract.pro** has the following content

```
QT     += core gui widgets xml

TARGET = pdf_extract
TEMPLATE = lib
DEFINES += DATASHEET_EXTRACTOR_EXPORT_LIB
DESTDIR = "$$PWD/../../bin"

CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
    CONFIG += optimize_full
}

SOURCES += \
    $$PWD/datasheet.cpp \
    $$PWD/datasheetpackage.cpp \
    $$PWD/datasheetpin.cpp \
    $$PWD/datasheetbox.cpp \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugwidget.cpp \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugviewer.cpp \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugscene.cpp \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugitempage.cpp \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugitempin.cpp \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugitemtextbox.cpp \
    $$PWD/model/pdfdatasheet.cpp \
    $$PWD/model/pdfpage.cpp \
    $$PWD/model/pdftextbox.cpp \
    $$PWD/model/pdfpin.cpp \
    $$PWD/model/pdfcomponent.cpp \
    $$PWD/controller/pdfloader.cpp

HEADERS += \
    $$PWD/pdf_extract_common.h \
    $$PWD/datasheet.h \
    $$PWD/datasheetpackage.h \
    $$PWD/datasheetpin.h \
    $$PWD/datasheetbox.h \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugwidget.h \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugviewer.h \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugscene.h \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugitempage.h \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugitempin.h \
    $$PWD/pdfdebugwidget/pdfdebugitemtextbox.h \
    $$PWD/model/pdfdatasheet.h \
    $$PWD/model/pdfpage.h \
    $$PWD/model/pdftextbox.h \
    $$PWD/model/pdfpin.h \
    $$PWD/model/pdfcomponent.h \
    $$PWD/controller/pdfloader.h

LIBS += -L"$$PWD/../../bin"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/jpeg62.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/libfreetype-6.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/libopenjp2.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/libpng12.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/libpoppler-80.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/libpoppler-qt5.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/libtiff3.dll"
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/zlib1.dll"

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../


LIBS += -lkicad

macx {
    LIBS += -L /usr/local/lib
    INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include 
}
```

yet when I try to build the project I get these errors... am not sure what am doing wrong or missing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [qmake documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs), using unix standards to specify linked libraries will work on Windows, too. Anyway, instead of

```
LIBS += -L"$$PWD/dll/jpeg62.dll"
```

I would try

```
LIBS += "-L$$PWD/dll" - ljpeg62
```

or just use Windows style:

```
LIBS += $$PWD/dll/jpeg62.dll
```

Comment: I used this format **LIBS += $$PWD/dll/jpeg62.dll** and it seems to work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

2 years late but i've also been wondering,

```
#include <QLibrary>
```

place your *.dll in your Debug/Release folder. e.g:

> build-test-Desktop_Qt_6_1_2_MinGW_64_bit-Debug/debug

now simply:

```
QLibrary lib("myLibrary.dll");

if (!lib.load())
    qDebug() << lib.errorString();
if (lib.load())
    qDebug() << "library loaded";
```

alternatively, rather than placing the DLL in debug folder you can set the location of the dll to

> c:/path/to/dll/yourdll.dll